# Where is Joomla's ServiceProviderInterface

Tags: php, joomla-4, dependency-injection

I am working my way through a [Joomla 4 component tutorial](https://blog.astrid-guenther.de/en/die-erste-ansicht-im-backend/). I have setup Visual Studio Code's Intelephense to be able to find Joomla classes using [includepath](https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=831&t=989086#p3641893). That seems to be working fine for the first php file in the tutorial, "[script.php](https://codeberg.org/astrid/j4examplecode/src/branch/t1/src/administrator/components/com_foos/script.php)" (for example, VS Code can find `Text::_()`).

However, the second php file, "[provider.php](https://codeberg.org/astrid/j4examplecode/src/branch/t1/src/administrator/components/com_foos/services/provider.php)", defines a class that derives from `Joomla\DI\ServiceProviderInterface`. Intelephense can't seem to find where that class is defined and, after looking through my local instance of Joomla's source code, neither can I.

Where is Joomla\DI\ServiceProviderInterface defined?

And if such dependencies are not part of the Joomla source code, where does Joomla get them from at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla's Dependency Injection package is available at https://github.com/joomla-framework/di .

Hopefully this saves someone else the few hours I spent tracking this down.

Likewise, retrieve Psr\Container\ContainerInterface from https://github.com/php-fig/container .